# Replacing Nan values with values from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I'm working on missing data.
I have a table with 2 millions rows like this:

```
main_category_en eco_score
mustard            60
mustard            62
mustard            NaN
cheese             20
NaN                1
cheese             NaN
```

I create a new Dataframe with the mean value of eco_score for each category: `df_mean`

```
main_category_en eco_score
mustard           61.5
cheese            20
```

I need to replace `NaN` values from the original df with the mean `eco_score` from `df_mean` when its possible. I need to obtain this:

```
main_category_en eco_score
mustard            60
mustard            62
mustard            61.5
cheese             20
NaN                1
cheese             20
```

I've tried `.fillna()` and `merge()` but rows were `main_category_en = NaN` are droped.
I'have comme to this loop:

```
def replace_mean(df, 'main_category_en', 'eco_score'):

    dt = df[['main_category_en','eco_score']] 
    dt = dt.dropna()
    dmeancat= dt.groupby('main_category_en').mean()

    for i in range (0, len(df)):
        print(i)
        if (pd.isna(df['main_category_en'][i]) == False) and (pd.isna(df['eco_score'][i]) == True) and (df['main_category_en'][i] in dmeancat.index):
            print(yes)
            #value = dmeancat.loc[(dmeancat.index == df['main_category_en'][i]), 'ecoscore_score_fr'].iloc[0]
            df.iloc[i,df.columns.get_loc('ecoscore_score_fr')] =  value
    return df
```

This loop works but it is very time-consuming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fill `NaN` on the original dataframe `df` with:

```
df['eco_score'] = df.groupby('main_category_en')['eco_score'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

```
  main_category_en  eco_score
0          mustard       60.0
1          mustard       62.0
2          mustard       61.0
3           cheese       20.0
4              NaN        NaN
5           cheese       20.0
```